# Pre-processing compile-time constant arrays in Java 1.4

Tags: java, signal-processing, compile-time-constant, java1.4

For a current project, my task is to optimize a DSP algorithm for a machine only capable of executing Java 1.4 bytecode. The algorithm requires a lot of computations of coefficients of e^(-2 * *i* * pi * n * k * C) for a frequency shift; in my case, k ranges from 0-10, and n ranges from 0-4095. C is a constant.

What i want to do in order to speed up the algorithm is to pre-compute these coefficients and, ideally, have that done **at compile time**.

Therefore, my question is:

can

```
private final static float[][] coefficientsReal = getCoefficientsReal();
private final static float[][] getCoefficientsReal(){
    float[][] coeffReal = new float[11][];
    for (int kk=0; kk<11;kk++){
        coeffReal[kk]= new float[4096];
        for (int nn = 0; nn < 4096; nn++){
             coeffReal[kk][nn] = Math.cos(-2 * (float)Math.PI * kk * nn * C);
        }
    }
    return coeffReal;
}
```

which should be constant and known at compile time, be expressed in any way, so that all computations are executed at compile time? If not, what would be another way do do these computations before loading the class (note that static initializers are executed before the class is used, but still at runtime)? And, additionally, if it is not possible to compute that before, why?

**Possible other options**

I thought about other ways to solve the problem

- File input: compute the coefficients with a script, write them to a file, read that file. I have no information about the file I/O speed on the machine
- Resources: Possibly, the array could be compiled into a resource. Same problem as file input (really?)
- Hard-coded. No one wants to do this, but maybe it is legitimate. Also, I care about my scroll wheel.
- Code generator. I would let some other program compute the coefficients and insert them into a template for my original code. Still, this would produce source files with a lot of unnecessary lines.

So far, I have not figured out which way would be the best to go.

Thank you for answers on my first question here!

Comment: At compile time you compile the code. You need to run that method and this is done at runtime. 11 * 4095 iterations are not too much for me. How much time does those loops take?

Comment: @FranMontero Constant folding is a fairly standard compile-time optimization, which does exactly what OP is asking: Doing computations during compilation, so they don't need to be done at runtime, saving time and power.

Also: 45056 iterations of a loop with multiple floating point operations may actually take a second or more, if the machine is small. I'm assuming OP is not using a powerful x86-based one.

Comment: "Code generator [...] would produce source files with a lot of unnecessary lines." - So?

Comment: @Delphinator everyday there is something to be learnt... thanks. Yo can compile you code and then check the generated bytecode to see if it was optimised by constant folding.

Comment: "if it is not possible to compute that before, why?" - The Java compiler (and the Java language ftm) has only limited complexity. It may 'see' some possible simple optimizations but will *not* execute complex Java code even if it could theoretically. - You may also want to check memory use of runtime vs. compile-time initialization of the array. For compile-time, best case will be that the whole array's contents are stored as literals in the .class file, increasing the file's size accordingly, where the few lines of code for runtime generation may yield a significantly smaller .class file.